# Best way to structure include/lib directories for CMake cross-compilation?

Tags: c++, cmake, arm, cross-compiling, toolchain

I have a general question that stems from a more specific issue I'm having with cross-compiling for aarch64/ARMv8.

First, my specific issue is that I can't seem to get my arm toolchain's ld binary to link against glibc/libc objects.

> example_path/aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory

I suppose that because it is an `.o`, I should probably use the one from my target platform instead of my host one. So I have copied sysroot from my target platform (no `bin`, just `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`), and I have added that into a directory in my workspace called aarch64. Now, in my `toolchain.cmake` file, I've set this, because I don't want to use an x86-64 libs or headers:

```
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT /usr/bin/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-linux-gnu)
```

Because `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY` is sent to `ONLY`, CMake should ignore usual library paths.
So this has led to my general question:

What is the best/most-commonly accepted way to structure directories etc for cross-compiling? Obviously, I don't want to put my target's sysroot in `/usr/...` but I need to be able to link against the ARM sysroot for all the libs installed there. Is it as simple as using:

```
link_directories(...)
```

in the toolchain file?
Where do people usually store the sysroot?
Thanks for your time, and apologies if this is a simple question - I am new to cross-compiling.

Comment: I've since changed CMAKE_SYSROOT to point to the target sysroot (in my toolchain_file.cmake), not the toolchain I am using on my x86/64 machine to compile. This has fixed the linking issues from the toolchains ld to the libc objects that belong to the target platform. I would still like an answer as to the best way to structure the directories for a project though